# How to check if an initialised struct is empty or not?

Tags: c, struct

So I want to check if my struct is empty or not. I declare my struct as a variable but DO not allocate memory.

`text* t;`

Later on I want to check with an if statement whether my struct is empty or not.
`if (t!=NULL)` does not seem to work as `t` has an address. Also doing something like `if (t->head != NULL)` gives me a segfault as I haven't allocated any memory for the struct.

I don't want to `malloc` as soon as I declare `t`. Is there a way to check if my struct is empty?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just make sure you initialise the pointer to `NULL`:

```
text* t = NULL;
```

then later you can `malloc` on demand, e.g.:

```
if (t == NULL)
{
    t = malloc(sizeof *t);
    // NB: check for error here - malloc can fail!
}
t->head = foo;
```

Comment: when using malloc(), and family of functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @user3629249: good point - I left error checking out for clarity, but I also don't want to encourage bad habits - I'll add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simply initialize the pointer whan it is defined

```
text* t = NULL;
```

In this case you can check whether an object that should be pointed to by the pointer was allocated

```
if ( t != NULL ) { /* some action */ }
```

or you can write

```
if ( t && t->head ) { /* some action */ }
```

Take into account that if a pointer is defined outside any function that is if it has the static storage duration then it initialized implicitly by the compiler to a null pointer constant.

Answer (score 0):

You do **not** declare the struct, but a *pointer* to the struct. You even *define* the pointer (bring it into life and reserve memory space for it).

To declare (and define) a *variable* of that struct (presumed it has been *declared* somewhere before with typedef):

```
text my_struct_var;
```

This will reserve the space at compile time. The struct is initialized with 0 by the run-time system before main() is called (this may also be done by the OS functions which load the program). This means all fields are set to 0.

If you stick to to pointer-approach, you first have to `malloc()` ("memory allocate") the required space for such an object (or an array of such objects) and assign it to the pointer. This allocation is called "dynamic", as the meory is allocated at run-time under program control. Similar, it can be `free()`d by the program code after which it must **never** be accessed again.

The allocated memory is **not** initialized, thus it *will* have random data. Therefore, you cannot test for anything inside.

A priciple problem with dynamic memory allocation is that it might fail (no momory available). Therefore, you always have to check the result of `malloc()`  if a valid pointer has been returned:

```
text *my_text_struct_ptr = malloc(sizeof(text));
if ( my_text_struct_ptr == NULL ) {
    // no memory allocated treat correspondingly
    // most basic reaction: exit(1) the program immediately
}
```

That might be what you call "the struct is empty". However, it is the *pointer* to the struct which is *invalid* ("points to nowhere"). For some more advanced data structures such a *null pointer* sometimes is a synptom ofthe structure bein empty (e.g. a list).

Further readings: about null pointers, declaration vs. definition, pointers and structs.